# Question about regression model selection

Tags: regression, cross-validation, model-selection, scikit-learn

I have a regression problem to solve and in order to find a suitable model, I use the following method:
1°) run a CV for each one with default param 
2°) Compare mean(MSE), STD(MSE) and calculation time
3°) Keep the quickest one with the best overall MSE

The models I tried 
•   RandomForest (scikit-learn)
•   GradiantBoosting (scikit-learn)
•   HistGradiantBoosting (scikit-learn, experimental)
•   Xgboost
•   Lighgbm

**My question:** 
Is my method correct?

Comment: Probably. Depends on your loss function (or utility function), i.e. what you want from your model.

Comment: I am using a MSE loss function because it's how the challenge is evaluate

Comment: If expected squared loss (which MSE is an estimate of) is a complete measure of your loss, why do you keep track of std(MSE) and the calculation time? If you care about std(MSE), what precisely are you optimizing? Expected value of some nonlinear function of squared error? And if you do care about the calculation time, it should be accounted for in your loss function (e.g. use $\text{MSE}+c \cdot \text{time}$ for some positive constant $c$ or something).

Comment: As Richard said, if computation time is a relevant factor it should be included in the loss function used. In addition, probably you want to decide between the computational time required to train a  model and the one make predictions from that model (or maybe both). Also, there is no mention to how the CV procedure is done and whether is stable in itself or whether the sample size is even adequate for what we want to model. Maybe make some checks on that too!